# How to configure SPI to LSB_FIRST mode?

Tags: raspbian, spi

I am trying to configure my Raspberry Zero W SPI interface to communicate lsb-first. I've modified [spidev_test.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/tools/spi/spidev_fdx.c), but when I run it, I get an error:

```
uint8_t lsb_first = 1;
ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_LSB_FIRST, &lsb_first);
if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't set lsbfirst");
```

> can't set lsbfirst: Invalid argument

If I set it to zero, it works.

**Does the Raspberry Pi not support lsb-first?**
And if so, why is this apparently not documented *anywhere*?

Comment: TBH I've no idea but as a workaround you can reverse the bit order in the byte you are sending and then transfer using the MSB code... Ugly 'hack' but if it keeps you on track...

Comment: Yeah, I considered that. Fastest example I found was to define a look-up table. In this particular case, it's probably simpler just to change the firmware of the slave device (I wrote it). But I want to know if the Pi *does actually* lack this basic functionality.

Comment: Can the coward who downvoted my question please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

For something to be documented you need to read the documentation.

The main SPI device (GPIO 7-11) has no support for changing the bit order.

The auxiliary SPI device (GPIO 16-21) supports changing the bit order.